# What we can infer from equating Taylor series for $(1+x)^n$ and binomial theorem for $(1+x)^n$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, taylor-expansion, recreational-mathematics, binomial-theorem

$(1+x)^n=1+\frac{(n)ln(1+x)}{1!}+\frac{(n^2)(ln(1+x))^2}{2!}+\frac{(n^3)(ln(1+x))^3}{3!}+\cdots$

$(1+x)^n=1+nx+(^nC_2){x^2}+(^nC_3){x^3+\cdots}$

Here, equating both the series doesn't make any sense of progress to get any sort of result since the former one contains natural logs of $(1+x)$ and the later one has factorial values attached to the variable $x$. So, comparing the coefficients looks like a tedious and cumbersome task. But I was still wondering if we can extract any result from the comparison of the two forms?

Comment: Shouldn't the Taylor series of a polynomial just be the terms of the polynomial starting with the terms of the lowest degree? For instance, the Taylor Series of $1+x+x^2+x^3...$ for any degree $n$ should just be the first $n$ terms.

Comment: I don't understand how you got the first equation with the natural logs in them.  How could differentiation of anything like $(1+x)^n$ produce natural logs?

Comment: The derivative of $(1+x)^n$ is just $n(1+x)^{n-1}*1$ by the chain rule.

Comment: The Taylor series of a polynomial is the same polynomial (or another polynomial if the expansion is not centered at 0). The first expression doesn't seem right. Where does the ln come from? Where is n in the rhs expression? How do you derive it?

Comment: @Emilio see the expansion of $a^n$ at http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%5En . Here a=1+x.

Comment: @ankit The link you gave is reading $a^n$ as an **exponential function**, not a polynomial.

Comment: @ankit: Note that it says "expansion at $n=0$", not at $a=1$...

Comment: OP was treating the first as $e^{n ln (1+x)}$, renaming $y=ln (1+x)$ and then doing an expansion in $y$. You could then do the expansion in $x$ of $y$ and plug in and that is the question I think. Note that $(ln(1+x))^n$ will start with $x^n$ so they won't show up until then. Also be careful about the domains with the $x=-1$ branch point.

Comment: I see you corrected the first expression. Wolfram gives you that expansion (for $n$) because when you put $a$ instead of $1+x$, it considers $a$ constant and $n$ variable

Comment: @Emilio To be pedantic, when centered at $a\neq0$, the Taylor series will yield the same polynomial, after expanding the $(x-a)^k$ terms.

Comment: @Aweygan true! I should have mentioned I was thinking of $x-a$ as a new variable

Comment: The series containing powers of logarithms of x is better called "Puisieux-series" to focus on the difference to a power series

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comment, what you did wrong,was to consider that $$(1+x)^n= e^{n\, \ln(1+x)}=e^y$$ and you did apply the expansion of $$e^y=1+y+ \frac{y^2}{2!}+ \frac{y^3}{3!}+\cdots$$ and making $y=n\ln(1+x)$ $$(1+x)^n=1+\frac{n\ln(1+x)}{1!}+\frac{n^2 \ln^2(1+x)}{2!}+\frac{n^3 \ln^3(1+x)}{3!}+\cdots\tag 1$$ which is your first expression.

However, you can still recover using Taylor expansion of $\ln(1+x)$ since $$\ln(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$\ln^2(1+x)=x-\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{x^3}{3}+O\left(x^4\right)=x^2-x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ $$\ln^3(1+x)=x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ Replacing in $(1)$, you then get $$(1+x)^n=1+n x+\left(\frac{n^2}{2}-\frac{n}{2}\right)
   x^2+\left(\frac{n^3}{6}-\frac{n^2}{2}+\frac{n}{3}\right) x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ which, after simplifications, leads to $$(1+x)^n=1+n x+\frac{1}{2} n(n-1)  x^2+\frac{1}{6} n(n-1)(n-2)  x^3+O\left(x^4\right)$$ which is your second expression.

You took a long way $\cdots$ but it works !

Comment: Here, we have derived binomial theorem from Taylor's theorem can we do the reverse?

Answer (score 1):

The first equation gives the Taylor series of $(1+x)^n$ as a function of $n$, very similar to the exponential function series but with a logarithm for the different basis. The second equation gives the Taylor series of $(1+x)^n$ as a function of $x$. That's why it's so difficult (and useless) to compare them